# In Azure Stream Analytics if a send failed, where can I see the reason for the failure

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have an input from an Azure Eventhub passing through a query and goint to an output which is an Azure SQL database. The stream was running for 2 days and suddenly I couldn't see the output in the database. On going to the Operational Logs section in Stream Analytics, I could just see a "Send Events" with a "Failed" status and an operational log id. Where can I find the reason of the failure? Also the data started coming into the database when I restarted the ASA job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry..found it..you have to highlight the error and click the details icon at the bottom of the page